# Ajax request returns `Page not found (404)` result

Tags: python, django, ajax

I know what that error means. I need your help to see my code, what I am doing wrong.

I want to create an `add to wishlist` button, here is the tag:

```
<a href="{% url 'listing:wishlist' %}" id="wishlistbtn" data-slug='{{ list.slug }}'>Add to wishlist</a>
```

urls.py

```
path('wishlist/', wishlist, name='wishlist'),
```

Ajax code in template:

```
$(document).on('click', '#wishlistbtn', function (e) {
    let el = $(this);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "/wishlist/",
        data: {
            title_slug: el.attr("data-slug"),
        },

        success: function () {
            alert('added to wishlist');
        }

    })
})
```

and here is the view:

```
def wishlist(request):
    slug = request.GET.get('title_slug')
    obj = get_object_or_404(Listing, slug=slug)
    profile = Profile.objects.all().filter(user=request.user).first()
    profile.wishlist.add(obj)
    
    return HttpResponse('true')
```

Kindly help me find the error and solve it.

Comment: You shouldn't have multiple elements in your HTML with the same `id`. Better would be to use a class - `class="wishlistbtn"` & `$(document).on('click', '.wishlistbtn', ...`

Comment: I guess there is only 1 element with `id='wishlistbtn'`

Comment: maybe it raised by get_object_or_404.

Comment: No i checked the database, it isn't the error from get_object_or_404

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the href from the a tag since you are not using it to navigate anywhere .. and then in the url in the ajax part  replace `/checkout/` with `{% url 'listing:wishlist' %}`

Comment: it doesn't add the item in the wishlist

Comment: You have `DEBUG=True` I guess .. What does it say exactly

Comment: `Not Found: /wishlist/
[22/Jun/2020 00:03:31] "GET /wishlist/?title_slug=cycle-neron HTTP/1.1" 404 1764` in terminal

Comment: If you visit the checkout link does it work ? Or does it return a 404 error ?